# Get the name of the node calling a service in the service callback

Tags: ros2, node, service, rclpy

In rclpy (python), I'm creating a service. How can this service tell the name of the node that is calling it?

My goal is to allow the service to check the node-name of the client before performing the service and responding. This way, if the node shouldn't be calling this service, it can fail somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in ROS 1 using the connection header. Requests have `_connection_header`, which is a python dictionary containing the `'callerid'`, which is what you want. Here's an example code snippet for ROS 1:

```
import rospy
from std_srvs.srv import Empty, EmptyResponse

rospy.init_node('test_srv')

def cb(req):
    print(req._connection_header.keys())
    print(req._connection_header['callerid'])
    return EmptyResponse()

rospy.Service('test_srv', Empty, cb)
rospy.spin()
```

Calling that service will display the name of the node calling it. For example, running `rosservice call /test_srv` will show the node produced by the `rosservice call` command (which will be of the format `/rosservice_<numbers>_<numbers>`).

It's not immediately clear to me how to do this in ROS 2. If this is an important feature to you, a more robust way of doing this might be to include this information in the Service message: that way, namespacing or renaming nodes won't break your core functionality. You should also perhaps reconsider your architecture: it's odd that you would be having nodes attach to a service that they're not 'allowed' to use.

Answer (score 0):

If clients are not trusted, then it is better to add create a new field in the .srv definition and send RSA key.

In python, you can use [this rsa package](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#generating-keys).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but it seems [`rclpy_get_client_names_and_types_by_node`](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/995bbed81cdb6bbcc2910c23ebfb280f8564c85f/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy_pybind11.cpp#L210) might provide that info, and
[`rclpy_get_service_names_and_types`](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/995bbed81cdb6bbcc2910c23ebfb280f8564c85f/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy_pybind11.cpp#L202) which node provides which services.